# Why does Chrome & Edge reject Set-Cookie as having invalid syntax, but not FireFox

Tags: google-chrome, cookies, setcookie

I am setting a header with php's `setcookie` like:

```
setcookie('xxx', 'xxx', ['path'=>'/', 'samesite'=>'Strict', 'secure'=>1, 'httponly'=>1]);
```

In their developer tool, both Chrome and Edge show:

```
    xxx=xxx; path=/; secure; HttpOnly; SameSite=Strict
```

with an orange triangle which states:
'This Set-Cookie header had a invalid syntax.' when hovered over.

There are no errors or warnings shown under the *Issues* tab, whereas leaving out any of the values shown above did.

FireFox has no problem and it sends it back with the next request.

Why is it so?

P.S.: It is running in https on a web-facing server. All latest browser versions.

For comparison, this is from a Samsung site, and it's ok:

```
JSESSIONID=371E1F0AFB88D3FBF0A1DF4B99432193; Path=/; Secure; HttpOnly
```

**Addendum**

The issue was that a separate `Clear-Site-Data` header included `"cookies"`, thus making Edge and Chrome ignore the cookie, but included a very misleading error message which gave no clue to where the problem lay.

Firefox saw no problem at all and used the cookie, but that may be because it doesn't clear the cookies out until after the next request. It is the response that tells the browser to clear all cookies, so why does Firefox sneak in one last request?

Clearly there is an inconsistency between browser engines as to when `Clear-Site-Data` should apply from.

All browsers should provide an error when a cookie is set but `Clear-Site-Data` tells it to clear the cookies. While not a breach of any technical specification, this is clearly a mistake that causes the cookie to fail in its purpose, and the developer needs to know why their code catastrophically fails.

**False reason for closing**

This question was closed as being `not reproducible or was caused by typos`.

This is false as it is both:

1. Currently reproducible (create a cookie and include `"cookies"` in  a `Clear-Site-Data` header) and
2. Not as a result of a typo (both contributors to the issue were deliberately constructed statements, even if the consequences were not clear, which is exactly the type of thing that SO can help people with).

I contend that it is the misleading error messages and inconsistent behaviour between browsers that this question and its solution may be of use.

Comment: As per the addition to the question body, the question is reproducible and not resulting from a typo. It is the disparate or misleading ways that browsers deal with the  conflict that such a question and answer are required. Please re-open, as that gives credence to it being a real issue. The real cookie that encountered this problem was for storing a session id, for which the deletion of the cookie caused the logins to fail on Chrome and Edge, but not Firefox. That is as real-world an issue as it gets.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Mea culpa!

There had to be a simple answer, and that was that another setting was preventing the cookie being used.

I had a `Clear-Site-Data` header that included "cookies". Removing "cookies' from that header meant the cookie became usable.

What was problematic was that Chrome and Edge gave misleading indicators, since the problem was not about invalid syntax at all.

FireFox seemed to have ignored the header altogether. Of course, there may some subtleties around when the cookies are deleted.

If anything, the browser developer tools could have listed a warning item that stated that the cookie was ignored due to the `Clear-Site-Data` header, since creating a cookie only to have it ignored before it could be used is likely to be a mistake or oversight, especially since the cookie couldn't be read by JavaScript due to `HttpOnly`, meaning that it couldn't access the cookie value before it would be ignored.

This issue is now solved.

Answer (score -1):

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_cookie):

> However, some browsers, including Chrome 52 and higher and Firefox 52 and higher, forgo this specification in favor of better security and forbid insecure sites (HTTP) from setting cookies with the `Secure` directive.

Perhaps you are running an older version of FireFox? Edge and Chrome are warning you that according to their stricter rules there is a contradiction between `secure` and `HttpOnly`.

Comment: All latest versions. Site is https and full web-facing